# ListView DataKeys[Index] Returning Random DataKeyName "Id" Number

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

Okay, this has been driving me insane today.
So I have the following markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvComments" DataKeyNames="Id, Sender, Likes" runat="server">
<EmptyDataTemplate>
```

etc...

Let's say I add a label as such: 
`<asp:Label ID="foo" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>`

**This returns the proper DataKey "Id".** Now in CodeBehind I am doing the following:

```
 protected void CommentUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     LinkButton CommentUp = (LinkButton)sender;
     ListViewItem CommentItem = CommentUp.NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
     ListView lvComments = (ListView)CommentItem.NamingContainer;

     int i = (Int32)lvComments.DataKeys[CommentItem.DisplayIndex].Values["Id"];
 }
```

However, i is returning '86' an integer which does not exist anywhere as the "Id" coming from the DataSource (*shown below*). This ListView is nested in another ListView and I am using the same technique on its parent to get the DataKey and it's working... I've also done this many times. I am unable to figure out why this is not returning the proper Id integer.

If it helps, here's how I'm populating my data:

```
public static List<Comment> GetAll(Int32 StreamId)
{
    const string sqlString =
        "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE StreamId = @StreamId;";

    List<Comment> list = new List<Comment>();
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = taaraf.GetConn();
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreamId", StreamId);

        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            Comment objComment = new Comment 
            {
                Id = (Int32)sqlReader.GetValue(0),
                Value = sqlReader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                Sender = sqlReader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                IsRead = taaraf.IntToBool((Int32)sqlReader["IsRead"]),
                StreamId = (Int32)sqlReader.GetValue(5) 
            };
            list.Add(objComment);
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();
        sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }
    return list;
}

...
lvComments.DataSource = Comment.GetAll(StreamId);
lvComments.DataBind();
...
```

Everything is nested in a UpdatePanel with specific triggers. If you need more details or anything please let me know below.

Comment: Can you enable debugging, and navigate to lvComment datakeys values and review all the values returned by listbox. Are they correct? Looks like something overwrites your integer.

Comment: They are not correct. But showing them using Eval insde the ListView shows the correct items.

Comment: Something is definitely missing. GetAll command return correct values, right?

Comment: Yes, GetAll returns the proper values.

Comment: Is it somehow possible that lvComments is resolving to the outer listview, instead of the inner one as you intended?

Comment: Hi wonkim00, I thought about that earlier, the Ids from the outer ListView control don't match the returned int i. If you guys need to see more code or anything please let me know and thanks for the support.

Comment: For exmaple the Id in the Database is 144 it is also returned correctly with the .GetAll function but i returns 90. 90 Exists nowhere in my database under any Id column.

Comment: The issue resolved itself, I am not sure how and why. Even though I am still getting the wrong Id values when using breakpoints and inspecting the integer value, It is updating the correct address in the database. I have no idea how this is happening and I'm not sure why I am still getting weird Id numbers.
So if you're looking for an answer to this, try the code and check if it is updating the right addresses in your database Visual Studio 2010 might show you wrong values. (Again, I am not sure why this is happening.) If anybody wants to see I can send screenshots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int i = (int)lvComments.DataKeys[CommentItem.DisplayIndex]["Id"];
```

**EDIT**

I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the fact you're using the `DisplayIndex`. Try using the `DataItemIndex` instead:

```
//double check and make sure that this is getting the correct item
ListViewItem commentItem = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;

if (commentItem != null)
{
    //instead of using the DisplayIndex use the DataItemIndex
    int id = (int)lvComments.DataKeys[commentItem.DataItemIndex]["Id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `enter code here` radcontrols,

In `itemdatabound` method:

```
if (   e.Item.ItemType ==    RadListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    RadListViewDataItem    `item `=    (RadListViewDataItem)e.Item;` 
    //here we read the DataKeys values from the item

    String EmpID = lstCompContctPerson.DataKeyValues[item.DataItemIndex]["CompanyContactPersonID"].ToString();`enter code here`
    hdnCompanyID.Value = EmpID;
}
```